# Apache error log

Tags: apache2

What mistake type is this and how to correct?

> [Sun Oct 31 12:00:07 2010] [error] [client 201.19.xxx.xx] File does not exist: /home/Example/public_html/url(res:, referer: http://www.example.com/mypage.htm

The indication of this url (**url(res:,**) appears a lot of times in the log

Apache 2.0.63
PHP 5.2.9

Comment: Is that real data? Is the referer for real?

Comment: Did you trigger this error? Or was another client you have no control of? Ideally, this could be the sympthom of a bug in your (PHP?) application

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a mistake in a CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Hah, good thinking! That's probably it. (Would +1 but I'm out of votes for today)

Comment: This mistake was copied of the log, I just changed URL for example.com

Comment: @Vera: Yes, but it means that some page requested something beginning with "url(res:/" which you usually do in CSS stylesheets.

Comment: Thank you, I will revise the pages and CSS stylesheets

Comment: I thank all help here.  
I still didn't get to solve the problem, but I identified the origin analyzing the error logs. Seemingly the mistake is generated by users using Google Toolbar:

/url(res://C:/Program%20Files/Google/Google%20Toolbar/Component/GoogleToolbarDynamic_mui_en_950DF09FAB501E03.dll/findy_buttons.png)  
  
I found the topic below but I didn't get to follow the suitable steps for the user chedar_ed in this topic:
http://www.webmasterworld.com/analytics/4221950.htm

Excuses for the mistakes, I don't speak English (I am using an automatic translator)